# C APIs to re-order XML elements?

Tags: c, xml

Are there any API's available in C which can re-order XML elements?

Sample input file will looks like below:

```
<A> a</A>
<B>b</B>
<C>
    <a1> a1</a1> 
     <a2>a2</a2>
```

D
I am  getting the input like above but i want to format the xml like below ( Where i will specify the What is order in which the xml elements should be present in the output in xslt).

```
<A> a</A>
<B>b</B>
<D>D</D>
<C>
    <a1> a1</a1> 
     <a2>a2</a2>
```

Are there any API in C which can do this? or is there any better way of ordering the XML elements.?

thanks,
Madhu

Comment: Madhu please give a more extensive example.   XML files are well formed, by changing order or tags you may destroy that form;  As for XML API there are a number of XML processing libraries out there.

Comment: You could at least give an XML example to make it clear what you want. Other than that: Yes, XSLT can do that - looks like a standard XML transformation to me - and yes, there are C XML/XSLT libraries such as `libxslt`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`libxml2`](http://xmlsoft.org/) library will do this.

You can do [Xpath queries](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/xpath1.c) to make subsets of your XML data: one for nodes exclusively *with* some attribute, a second query for nodes exclusively *without* same attribute, and then repeatedly on subsets with two or more nodes, until you get a [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of your set of parent nodes that you can print out in the desired order.

For example, the *with* attribute result is, let's say, the `C` node in your example. The *without* attribute result are the nodes `A`, `B`, and `D`. Now that you have two result sets, you can search on the *without* set to get the `B` result. At the end of three queries, you have three subsets of XML nodes: `{A, D}`, `{C}`, and `{B}`.

With these results in hand, creating a document with the new order `{A, D, B, C}` is just a matter of printing out the subsets in that order.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to solve this, is to use an XSLT processor such as the [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/) C library, that is closely related (actually, pretty much a part of) [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/). Probably the most popular XML processing library.

With an XSLT stylesheet, you have the **textbook way of restructuring XML** documents available.

Alternatively, you can also do it manually with `libxml2`, of course.